# Query to sum amount per store

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The job given to me was to edit the query, but I could not do the operation I wanted. First of all, the query output I want to explain is as follows:

```
FacilityName     AmountWithoutDiscount      DiscountedAmount
Atlantis             18.305                    12.335
OneTower             4.595                     3.168
Panora               10.043                    6.831
Grand Total          32.944                    22.334
```

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g.FacilityName, SUM(g.BrutPrice) AS AmountWithoutDiscount, SUM(g.NetPrice) AS DiscountedAmount
From(
SELECT e.FacilityName, b.ItemAmount, b.BrutPrice, b.NetPrice,
(SELECT DISTINCT f.ProductId FROM FAZIKI.dbo.NM_ProductCampaign f WHERE c.Id = f.ProductId AND (f.IsActive=1) AND (f.CampaignId='7') AND (f.ProductId IS NOT NULL)) as Product
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_InvoiceInformation a
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_InvoiceDetail b ON a.Id = b.InvoiceId 
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product c ON b.ProductId = c.Id 
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_GNFacility e ON a.FacilityId = e.Id
WHERE(a.InvoiceDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-11-08 00:00:00', 102)) AND (a.InvoiceType = 2) AND (a.IsFromNCR = 1) 
AND (c.RayonId = 1) AND (b.BrutPrice <> b.NetPrice) AND (a.IsCancel = 0)) AS g
WHERE g.Product IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY g.FacilityName,g.BrutPrice, g.NetPrice
```

query result:

```
FacilityName  AmountWithoutDiscount    DiscountedAmount
Atlantis           8.50                   5.74
Atlantis           8.50                   5.75
Atlantis           8.50                   5.77
.
.
.
OneTower          8.50                    5.70
OneTower          8.50                    5.83
OneTower          8.50                    5.87
.
.
.
Panora           8.50                     5.66
Panora           8.50                     5.78
Panora           8.50                     5.81
```

How can I do the sum of my query result as in the field I mentioned above and the sum of each store? I brought my query up to a certain point, but I could not do more. Can you help me?

Comment: Just some tips: A `GROUP BY` together with a `DISTINCT` is almost always incorrect. Also, think about what happens when you `GROUP BY` a column you are also using `SUM()` on

Comment: Please provide sample data starting data.

Comment: The reason I added DISTINCT was to reduce the store names to single data, but I couldn't. After removing DISCINT, the result did not change either. I want to reduce the field that says FacilityName to 3 in total. That is, a record and sum of all of them. Can you help me? @HoneyBadger

Comment: Main trouble is that you group by the exact columns you want to sum.

Comment: When I removed Group by, this time "Column 'g.Facility Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I am getting the error in SQL. When I use Group by, I cannot collect the columns as you said. @KnutBoehnert

Comment: You shouldn't remove the entire `GROUP BY`, you should `GROUP BY` the columns which are not in an aggregating function (`MAX()`, `AVG()`, `SUM()` etc). Like I said, think about what a `GROUP BY` does

Comment: Yes, you're right, sir, I removed the g.BrutPrice, g.NetPrice statements from Group by, and now I can make any query I want. Thank you very much, I am very grateful to you. I have one more question sir, now I have 3 column fields and how can I write a query that will take their sum and display it in a new row? @HoneyBadger

Comment: @burak Please don't asume my gender, I haven't told you I'm a "sir" or not. If you have another question, please post a new question (after research so you can fix it yourself first, naturally)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just wanted to show my respect for you. Thank you very much again @HoneyBadger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should delete from your query:

1. Distinct - there is no point in having "group by" and "distinct".
2. g.BrutPrice and g.NetPrice from the group by. If you have them in group by there is no point to use aggregation function such as "sum" on them.

so:

```
SELECT g.FacilityName, SUM(g.BrutPrice) AS AmountWithoutDiscount, SUM(g.NetPrice) AS DiscountedAmount
From(
SELECT e.FacilityName, b.ItemAmount, b.BrutPrice, b.NetPrice,
(SELECT DISTINCT f.ProductId FROM FAZIKI.dbo.NM_ProductCampaign f WHERE c.Id = f.ProductId AND (f.IsActive=1) AND (f.CampaignId='7') AND (f.ProductId IS NOT NULL)) as Product
FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_InvoiceInformation a
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_InvoiceDetail b ON a.Id = b.InvoiceId 
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.PM_Product c ON b.ProductId = c.Id 
INNER JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_GNFacility e ON a.FacilityId = e.Id
WHERE(a.InvoiceDate > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-11-08 00:00:00', 102)) AND (a.InvoiceType = 2) AND (a.IsFromNCR = 1) 
AND (c.RayonId = 1) AND (b.BrutPrice <> b.NetPrice) AND (a.IsCancel = 0)) AS g
WHERE g.Product IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY g.FacilityName
```

Comment: Yes. Totally true. I was thinking I should put them all in Group by but it disables the Sum functions. DISCINT was also an unnecessary expression. Thank you very much, I am very grateful to you.